# Can't create extensions plv8 postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plv8

After install postgres, can't create extension plv8.

I'm use: `CREATE EXTENSION plv8;`

I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/plv8.control": No such file or directory
********** Error **********

ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/plv8.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

version postgres: 9.6.2
version pgAdmin4: 1.4

How to install plv8?

Comment: Can you give a detailed description of how you installed plv8? What is your operating system?

Comment: https://pgxn.org/dist/plv8/doc/plv8.html#installing-plv8, btw it says PG: version 9.2, 9.3, 9.4 and 9.5 (maybe older/newer are allowed)

Comment: OS: Mac OS El Capitano
I'm installing plv8 therefore guide: https://github.com/plv8/plv8/blob/master/doc/plv8.md#installing-plv8

Comment: Forgot to ask, can someone else know why it does not work `brew install plv8` ?

Answer (score 3):

This should work on most platforms (https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues/212#issuecomment-287589193):

```
$ easy_install pgxnclient
$ pgxnclient install plv8
```

It didn't work for me though. The only solution I came up with was **building the library from source**.

If you don't have **wget** installed, run:

```
$ brew install wget
```

Then run:

```
$ wget https://github.com/plv8/plv8/archive/v2.0.0.tar.gz
$ tar -xvzf v2.0.0.tar.gz
$ cd plv8-2.0.0
$ make static
$ make install
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Note that `$ make static` requires python 2.7 (python 3 won't work)

Answer (score 3):

I. [Docker-images with postgres and plv8](https://hub.docker.com/r/sibedge/postgres-plv8). It's free, images for PostgreSQL 16, PostgreSQL 15, PostgreSQL 14 and PostgreSQL 13 based on Debian and Alpine are available, amd64 and arm64 (with Apple silicon M1/M2/M3 support) architectures maintaned.

```
docker pull sibedge/postgres-plv8
```

Default is Alpine/last Postgres version. [the complete tag list](https://hub.docker.com/r/sibedge/postgres-plv8/tags)

Pay attention, that BigInt is not serializable in v8 and [by default in plv8 v3.0.0 and higher BigInt numbers are converted into string(!)](https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues/485). But if you need BigInt as numbers support, use this image with Postgres and specific version of plv8:

```
docker pull sibedge/postgres-plv8-bigint
```

II. Or, you can build images (for PostgreSQL with installed plv8) yourself with Dockerfiles:

[Postgres 14.2, plv8 v3.0.0](https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build/blob/pg14-3.0.0-alpine/docker/Dockerfile), Alpine based. size of image is 235MB.

[Postgres 13.6, plv8 v3.0.0](https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build/blob/pg13-3.0.0-alpine/docker/Dockerfile), Alpine based. size of image is 231MB.

[Postgres 13.4, plv8 v2.13.15](https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build/blob/pg13-2.3.15/docker/Dockerfile), Debian based. size of image is 351MB.

[Postgres 13.6, plv8 v3.0.0](https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build/blob/pg13-3.0.0-debian/docker/Dockerfile), Debian based. size of image is 427MB.

III. Simple installing plv8 v3.0.0 on Debian Linux (PostgreSQL 13 must be preinstalled) :

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sibedge-llc/plv8-build.git
$ cd plv8-build
$ git checkout pg13-3.0.0-debian
$ sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a new way. Just copy and Paste!
if you using postgresql version of: 9.5, 9.6 beta, 10 go this link to download package and learn what shoud you copy and where to past:
https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/blob/master/documentation/documentation/admin/installing-plv8-windows.md

if you using postgresql version of: 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 10, 11 and 12 for downloading package you can go here:
http://updates.xtuple.com/updates/plv8/win/xtuple_plv8.zip
for downloading package and then copy past like has mentioned in first link

Comment: another link you can use it: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/379-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-10-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.htmll